# What is the correct way to solve a least square equation with eigen?

Tags: c++, eigen

I have the following simple example to perform a least square, but got the following assertion error.

> Assertion failed: (i>=0) && ( ((BlockRows==1) &&
>   (BlockCols==XprType::ColsAtCompileTime) && i

What is the correct way to do this?

```
typedef Eigen::ArrayXd arr;
typedef Eigen::ArrayXXd arr2;

arr2 A(3, 3);
arr B(3);
A << 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1;
B << 1, 2, 3;
auto x = A.matrix().colPivHouseholderQr().solve(B.matrix());
```

Comment: `A << 1, 0, ...` is just like `A << 1`, the numbers after the first comma are not part of the first expression.

Comment: I printed out A, it is the identity matrix.  @NiklasR

Comment: My bad, seems like it works as you intended. Thought the C++ syntax would result in a different behaviour here.

Comment: @NiklasR Eigen overloads the comma operator so that it can be used to assign values to a matrix.

Comment: Works for me, but you need to replace `auto` by `VectorXd` otherwise `x` will be an abstract expression storing a dead reference to the QR factorization. See https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicPitfalls.html

Comment: @ggael , you should make it an answer because, sure enough for me, that makes it work. `arr2 x = A....` Even though it compiles fine with `auto`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said in my comment, the problem is that `x` is an abstract expression storing a reference to the QR object, but right after the last line it will reference a dead object and then anything can happen!

More precisely, `A.matrix().colPivHouseholderQr()` creates a temporary object, let's call it `tmp_qr`. Then `tmp_qr.solve(B)` creates another object which becomes `x` of type `Solve<...>`. This object essentially stores two references: one to `tmp_qr`, and one to `B`. Right after this line, the temporary object `tmp_qr` is deleted, so the `Solve<...>` object `x` has one dead reference. It is like a pointer referencing a deleted buffer. Finally, if you `x` later, like:

```
VectorXd y = x;
```

`operator=` will trigger the solve operation using the QR decomposition referenced by `x` and the right-hand-side `B` referenced by `x` too, but, wait... the QR decomposition object has been deleted, so at best you'll get a segfault.

So the solution is to write:

```
VectorXd x = A.matrix().colPivHouseholderQr().solve(B.matrix());
```

See Eigen's [doc](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicPitfalls.html) for more details on how `auto` is dangerous if you don't know what you get.

Comment: I read the doc, but still cannot make sense why auto would cause errors. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I edited my answer to fully explain what's going one. Hope its clear now. If not, you might need to read about temporary lifetimes in C/C++.

Comment: I understand the dead reference problem you refer to. The part i am confused about is why auto causes the dead reference, but VectorXd avoids it. Isnt auto resolved at compile time to be VectorXd?

Comment: No, that's the point, with `auto x` the type of `x` is a `Solve<...>` abstract expression storing the references....