# Eigen 3 assert fails when solving a linear system - as far as I can tell it's due to an invalid index from within Eigen

Tags: c++, eigen

I am attempting to use Eigen to solve a system of linear equations of the form: Ax = b. A is a 45x45 matrix, b is a 45x1 Matrix, I expect to get a 45x1 solution.  However, the solver never returns. It fails when it aborts because there is an attempt to access index -4591537738753454899 of one of the matrices.  This is of course an invalid index. However I'm not generating this index, Eigen is.

It is entirely probable that I'm doing something silly, either with C++ or with my Linear Algebra to cause this, but I'm not seeing it. Any ideas?

**This is the code:**

```
using Matrix = Eigen::Matrix<ScalarT, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::ColMajor>;
using Vector = Eigen::Matrix<ScalarT, Eigen::Dynamic, 1, Eigen::ColMajor>;
auto x0 = problem.get_x_as_vector();
auto B = problem.get_hessian();
auto g = problem.get_gradient();
std::cout
    << " B.rows(): " << B.rows()
    << " B.cols(): " << B.cols()
    << " g.rows(): " << g.rows()
    << " g.cols(): " << g.cols()
    << std::endl;
Eigen::FullPivLU<decltype(B)> lu_decomp(B);
std::cout << B.determinant() << std::endl;
std::cout << "The rank of A is " << lu_decomp.rank() << std::endl;
std::cout << B << std::endl;
std::cout << g << std::endl;
auto p = B.fullPivHouseholderQr().solve(-g);
std::cout << "p" << std::endl;
std::cout << p << std::endl; // this is exact_newton.hpp:130
```

**This results in this output:**

```
A.rows(): 45 A.cols(): 45 b.rows(): 45 b.cols(): 1
The determinant of A is: -6.53094e+193
The rank of A is 45
A:45
 14848  -7168   9728   2048  17920   1536    512    512  -8192   5632   3072   5120  15872   4096   2560   8704   7680  10240      0  14336  -1536   7168  -3072   6656    512  10240  -4096   3584   2048  -1536   7680   7168   7168  -1024   3584 -11776   3072  -1024   5120   6144  15872  -5120   -512   6656   3584
 -7168 -27136 -10240  -8704   1024  -6144 -16896 -17920 -18432  -8704 -16896  -2560 -11264  -9728  -5632  -3072   1024  -8192 -10752   5120 -12288 -13824 -18432 -11264 -23040  -9216 -20480  -4096 -12288  -1024 -17408 -11776 -16384 -23040    512 -20992 -13312 -17408  -2560  -8192   4608 -28160 -11776   4096 -10752
  9728 -10240   1024  -5632  13312   -512   2560   6656 -14848  10752   1536   8704   2560  -6656   7168   6144   5120  -4608   1024  16384   2560   1024  -4096   4096 -10240   3584 -10240   6656   6656    512   5632   4096  -4096   6656  -3584  -9728  -2560   -512  10752   2560  22528  -6144      0  12288  10752
  2048  -8704  -5632  -1024   6144   2048  -6656  -7680  -5632   -512  -2560  10240  -3584  -8192   2560  -3584  -8192   2560   2560   8704  -7680  -1024  -1536  -3584 -12288   3072 -17408  -1024  -8704   -512 -12288   8192    512  -6144  -2560 -14848  -8192  -9728  -1024      0  17408 -11776  -4096   7680  -2560
 17920   1024  13312   6144  25088   6144  11264   7680   2560  11776   4096  19968   9216  12800  11776  17408  17408   8704   8192  22016  15872  18944   4608   8704  -3584  14848  -4608  12800  16384  13824  16384   5120   9216   5120   2048  -3584    512    512   4096  11776  18432    512   9216  10240  11264
  1536  -6144   -512   2048   6144   1536  -3584  -3584  -3072  -3072  -8704  11776   1024  -3584   4608  12288   1024   6144  -2048  12288  -6144   3584  -3072  -6656  -8192   9728 -12288   4608    512   6144  -2048   7168      0   -512  -3584 -13824  -1536  -2560   6656  -3072  12288  -5632      0   9216   1536
   512 -16896   2560  -6656  11264  -3584 -11776   -512 -12288  -5632   1536   9216  -1024  -9216  -2048   6656   2048      0      0   9216  -6656      0  -5120  -3584  -3584  -1536 -15360  -1536   -512   1536  -4096   3584  -3584   2048 -10752 -15360  -2560  -6144   3584  -1536   7168 -15360 -12288  -3584  -2048
   512 -17920   6656  -7680   7680  -3584   -512  -6144 -11776  -6656  -3072   1536   4096  -5120  -6144   7680  -2560   6144  -4096      0  -3072   3072  -5632  -4096 -14336  10240  -8192    512   1024   5120  -7168   2560  -1536  -4096 -11264  -9216  -3072   -512    512  -1024   8704 -16896   -512   7680  -6144
 -8192 -18432 -14848  -5632   2560  -3072 -12288 -11776      0   6144 -11264   4608  -3584 -13312 -22016   2048  -7680  -1536  -5120   2560  -5632  -2048  -9728  -6144 -10752  -1024  -6656 -11264  -3584  -4608  -7680  -1024 -10752  -9728  -8192 -19968 -15360 -11776  -9216   2560   1536 -11776   -512   8704 -12288
  5632  -8704  10752   -512  11776  -3072  -5632  -6656   6144   5120  -7168  11264   1024    512   5632   7680  13824   9216  -2048   9216   1024   9728   1536  -1536  -9216   8704 -13824   1024   1024   5120   3584   3584   2048 -11264  -4096  -9216   4608 -12288   -512   3584  12288 -12800  -3584   9728   2048
  3072 -16896   1536  -2560   4096  -8704   1536  -3072 -11264  -7168 -10752   8704  -7680 -16896  -5120   6656   2560   6144  -5632  -1024  -8192      0  -7168      0 -10752  -3072 -14848   4608  -4608  -1024  -8704 -11264 -11264  -9216   4096 -15872  -6656 -12288 -13312  -3072   1024 -21504  -9728   3584  -4096
  5120  -2560   8704  10240  19968  11776   9216   1536   4608  11264   8704  15360  11264    512   4096  12800  17920  14848  12800  17920   1536  -1536   8704      0  -1024   4608   1536  12288   8192  11264   5632   3072  19456   2048      0   -512   4096    512   8192   6656  24064  -6144   8704  17920  -1024
 15872 -11264   2560  -3584   9216   1024  -1024   4096  -3584   1024  -7680  11264   2048      0   1024   5120   2560   9216   -512  12800  -2560   2560  -5120   6144  -5632   7168  -7168   9216  -5120   9216    512   3072      0   -512  -2560  -6144  -5632  -4608   1536  -2560  18944  -4608  -2560   2048 -10240
  4096  -9728  -6656  -8192  12800  -3584  -9216  -5120 -13312    512 -16896    512      0 -17920  -9728   3584  -3584   2560  -8192   5120  -2560  -3584  -8704  -6144 -14848   1024  -9216    512  -8192   4608   1024  -3072  -4608 -14848 -13312 -15360 -12800  -6144   3072  -1536   9216 -17920  -6656   7680  -4096
  2560  -5632   7168   2560  11776   4608  -2048  -6144 -22016   5632  -5120   4096   1024  -9728      0   8192   2560  -1024  -3072  -2048  -6144   3072  -6656  -1024 -11776  -6144  -8192   1024   7168   3072  -7680   5632 -10240  -4608   2560 -11264  -1024  -5632   1024   5632  10240 -23040  -4096   4096 -16896
  8704  -3072   6144  -3584  17408  12288   6656   7680   2048   7680   6656  12800   5120   3584   8192  20480   1024  16384   6144  16896   1024   8192  -5120  11264  -4096   6656      0  10752   3072   3584   1536      0   3584   2048   -512  -3584   2048   2048   1536   8192  17920 -11776    512   4096  -3072
  7680   1024   5120  -8192  17408   1024   2048  -2560  -7680  13824   2560  17920   2560  -3584   2560   1024   6656   5632   5632  19456  -3584   7680  -9728   2048 -16384   1536  -9728  12288   2560   7680   2560   3584  -2048   1536   5632   2560  -4096  -1024   6656  10240  12288 -13312   2560  13312      0
 10240  -8192  -4608   2560   8704   6144      0   6144  -1536   9216   6144  14848   9216   2560  -1024  16384   5632   3072  10240  11264      0   8192  -4096   4096  -9728  10240  -9216   4608   2560   8192   2048   4096   6144   -512   1024  -8704   3584  -4608   4096   2048  17920 -11776    512  12800  -8192
     0 -10752   1024   2560   8192  -2048      0  -4096  -5120  -2048  -5632  12800   -512  -8192  -3072   6144   5632  10240  -1536   6144  -5632   -512  -6656   6656  -9216   8704 -13312   1024  -6656  -2048  -2048   7168  -3072  -4608   1536 -15360  -1024  -4608  -1024   7168  13824 -19968   6656  12288   4096
 14336   5120  16384   8704  22016  12288   9216      0   2560   9216  -1024  17920  12800   5120  -2048  16896  19456  11264   6144  19456   5632   3072  -2560  10752  -5632  15872  -4096  13312  16384  11264   2048  12800   4608   5632   9216  -2560   6656   2560  15360  19456  17920  -9216   7168  24064   4096
 -1536 -12288   2560  -7680  15872  -6144  -6656  -3072  -5632   1024  -8192   1536  -2560  -2560  -6144   1024  -3584      0  -5632   5632  -1536   5120    512  -1024  -1024      0 -17408   5632  -6656  -5120   2048  13312  -4096  -5632  -8704 -15360  -8192 -15360   3072   7168   8704 -20992  -8192  10240  -4608
  7168 -13824   1024  -1024  18944   3584      0   3072  -2048   9728      0  -1536   2560  -3584   3072   8192   7680   8192   -512   3072   5120   -512    512   2048  -8704  11264  -9216   6656   -512  18944  -2048   1024   3584  -4608      0  -3072  -2048  -3072  -2560   8192  15872 -13824  -8704  11264    512
 -3072 -18432  -4096  -1536   4608  -3072  -5120  -5632  -9728   1536  -7168   8704  -5120  -8704  -6656  -5120  -9728  -4096  -6656  -2560    512    512  -9216  -4096 -11264      0 -15872   5120  -6144   -512  -8704  -2048   -512 -12288  -3072 -14848 -10240 -18944 -10752   5120  10240 -21504  -6144   2048  -6144
  6656 -11264   4096  -3584   8704  -6656  -3584  -4096  -6144  -1536      0      0   6144  -6144  -1024  11264   2048   4096   6656  10752  -1024   2048  -4096  -4608  -9728  16896 -10240   1024   2048   4096   3584   2048   -512  -8192      0  -6656 -11776  -7680   1024   6656  10752 -12288  -5120  11776  -1024
   512 -23040 -10240 -12288  -3584  -8192  -3584 -14336 -10752  -9216 -10752  -1024  -5632 -14848 -11776  -4096 -16384  -9728  -9216  -5632  -1024  -8704 -11264  -9728 -22016      0 -29184  -8192  -6144 -10752 -13312  -4608  -7680 -13824 -12288 -16384 -20480 -16384  -4608  -5632    512 -18944 -18432 -10240  -6144
 10240  -9216   3584   3072  14848   9728  -1536  10240  -1024   8704  -3072   4608   7168   1024  -6144   6656   1536  10240   8704  15872      0  11264      0  16896      0   1536  -4608   9728   2560   5120   1536   7680  -1536   1024   -512  -8192   4096      0   4096  10752   9216 -12288  -3584  13312   6656
 -4096 -20480 -10240 -17408  -4608 -12288 -15360  -8192  -6656 -13824 -14848   1536  -7168  -9216  -8192      0  -9728  -9216 -13312  -4096 -17408  -9216 -15872 -10240 -29184  -4608 -16384  -4096 -15872 -10240 -19456  -4096 -17920 -21504  -7168 -20480 -19968 -10752  -6656  -4096  -8704 -21504  -5120  -4608 -13312
  3584  -4096   6656  -1024  12800   4608  -1536    512 -11264   1024   4608  12288   9216    512   1024  10752  12288   4608   1024  13312   5632   6656   5120   1024  -8192   9728  -4096   3072   2048  -4608  -2048   2560   7168  -2560  -4096  -9216  -1536  -6144  -4608   4608  16384 -11264  -1024   8704  -1024
  2048 -12288   6656  -8704  16384    512   -512   1024  -3584   1024  -4608   8192  -5120  -8192   7168   3072   2560   2560  -6656  16384  -6656   -512  -6144   2048  -6144   2560 -15872   2048  -3584    512  -5120  -3584  -1024  -9728  -3072 -10752  -9728  -9216  -3072  -1024  12800  -8192    512  13824  -6656
 -1536  -1024    512   -512  13824   6144   1536   5120  -4608   5120  -1024  11264   9216   4608   3072   3584   7680   8192  -2048  11264  -5120  18944   -512   4096 -10752   5120 -10240  -4608    512   6144  -6144   4096   7168   1024   4096 -13824 -10240   4096  10752   5120  10240 -12800   5632  11264   3584
  7680 -17408   5632 -12288  16384  -2048  -4096  -7168  -7680   3584  -8704   5632    512   1024  -7680   1536   2560   2048  -2048   2048   2048  -2048  -8704   3584 -13312   1536 -19456  -2048  -5120  -6144    512   5120  -1536  -2048  -4608 -13824  -9728  -5120  -4096   1024  12288 -14336 -14848   6144  -8704
  7168 -11776   4096   8192   5120   7168   3584   2560  -1024   3584 -11264   3072   3072  -3072   5632      0   3584   4096   7168  12800  13312   1024  -2048   2048  -4608   7680  -4096   2560  -3584   4096   5120  17408   4608    512  -4608  -3072  -6144   1536  -2048   5120   8192  -2560   3072   3584   6656
  7168 -16384  -4096    512   9216      0  -3584  -1536 -10752   2048 -11264  19456      0  -4608 -10240   3584  -2048   6144  -3072   4608  -4096   3584   -512   -512  -7680  -1536 -17920   7168  -1024   7168  -1536   4608  10240 -16896 -12288 -14848  -3584  -5632   4608  -1536  18432 -11776  -6656  12800  -2048
 -1024 -23040   6656  -6144   5120   -512   2048  -4096  -9728 -11264  -9216   2048   -512 -14848  -4608   2048   1536   -512  -4608   5632  -5632  -4608 -12288  -8192 -13824   1024 -21504  -2560  -9728   1024  -2048    512 -16896 -13312  -5120 -20992  -7680  -7680  -9728  -4608   7168  -8704  -9728  11776  -2048
  3584    512  -3584  -2560   2048  -3584 -10752 -11264  -8192  -4096   4096      0  -2560 -13312   2560   -512   5632   1024   1536   9216  -8704      0  -3072      0 -12288   -512  -7168  -4096  -3072   4096  -4608  -4608 -12288  -5120  -4096 -10240 -16384  -6656   -512   4608   2048 -10752  -3072   -512  -1536
-11776 -20992  -9728 -14848  -3584 -13824 -15360  -9216 -19968  -9216 -15872   -512  -6144 -15360 -11264  -3584   2560  -8704 -15360  -2560 -15360  -3072 -14848  -6656 -16384  -8192 -20480  -9216 -10752 -13824 -13824  -3072 -14848 -20992 -10240 -21504 -10240 -19968  -7680 -11776   5632 -18432 -12800   3072 -10240
  3072 -13312  -2560  -8192    512  -1536  -2560  -3072 -15360   4608  -6656   4096  -5632 -12800  -1024   2048  -4096   3584  -1024   6656  -8192  -2048 -10240 -11776 -20480   4096 -19968  -1536  -9728 -10240  -9728  -6144  -3584  -7680 -16384 -10240 -12800  -5120 -18432   1024   4608 -13312  -8704  -4096  -5632
 -1024 -17408   -512  -9728    512  -2560  -6144   -512 -11776 -12288 -12288    512  -4608  -6144  -5632   2048  -1024  -4608  -4608   2560 -15360  -3072 -18944  -7680 -16384      0 -10752  -6144  -9216   4096  -5120   1536  -5632  -7680  -6656 -19968  -5120  -1536  -7680   3584   3584 -13824  -6656  12288  -4096
  5120  -2560  10752  -1024   4096   6656   3584    512  -9216   -512 -13312   8192   1536   3072   1024   1536   6656   4096  -1024  15360   3072  -2560 -10752   1024  -4608   4096  -6656  -4608  -3072  10752  -4096  -2048   4608  -9728   -512  -7680 -18432  -7680   -512   6144   9216 -15872  -5632   3584  -9728
  6144  -8192   2560      0  11776  -3072  -1536  -1024   2560   3584  -3072   6656  -2560  -1536   5632   8192  10240   2048   7168  19456   7168   8192   5120   6656  -5632  10752  -4096   4608  -1024   5120   1024   5120  -1536  -4608   4608 -11776   1024   3584   6144  -1536  10240 -14848  -5632   5632  -3584
 15872   4608  22528  17408  18432  12288   7168   8704   1536  12288   1024  24064  18944   9216  10240  17920  12288  17920  13824  17920   8704  15872  10240  10752    512   9216  -8704  16384  12800  10240  12288   8192  18432   7168   2048   5632   4608   3584   9216  10240  22528      0   1536  17408   1536
 -5120 -28160  -6144 -11776    512  -5632 -15360 -16896 -11776 -12800 -21504  -6144  -4608 -17920 -23040 -11776 -13312 -11776 -19968  -9216 -20992 -13824 -21504 -12288 -18944 -12288 -21504 -11264  -8192 -12800 -14336  -2560 -11776  -8704 -10752 -18432 -13312 -13824 -15872 -14848      0 -25600 -12800 -10752 -12800
  -512 -11776      0  -4096   9216      0 -12288   -512   -512  -3584  -9728   8704  -2560  -6656  -4096    512   2560    512   6656   7168  -8192  -8704  -6144  -5120 -18432  -3584  -5120  -1024    512   5632 -14848   3072  -6656  -9728  -3072 -12800  -8704  -6656  -5632  -5632   1536 -12800  -6656  -3584  -5120
  6656   4096  12288   7680  10240   9216  -3584   7680   8704   9728   3584  17920   2048   7680   4096   4096  13312  12800  12288  24064  10240  11264   2048  11776 -10240  13312  -4608   8704  13824  11264   6144   3584  12800  11776   -512   3072  -4096  12288   3584   5632  17408 -10752  -3584  20992  -1536
  3584 -10752  10752  -2560  11264   1536  -2048  -6144 -12288   2048  -4096  -1024 -10240  -4096 -16896  -3072      0  -8192   4096   4096  -4608    512  -6144  -1024  -6144   6656 -13312  -1024  -6656   3584  -8704   6656  -2048  -2048  -1536 -10240  -5632  -4096  -9728  -3584   1536 -12800  -5120  -1536  -4096
b:45
 47.1621
-32.8494
 30.0294
 -8.9893
-5.28092
 4.61713
-16.9991
 19.4085
 19.5158
-17.1755
 4.64882
-5.27878
-8.95621
 29.9769
-32.8287
-110.201
 74.2029
-65.0509
 18.8271
 12.4264
-12.0408
 40.8423
-42.3031
-42.5339
 41.2273
-12.1228
 12.4332
 18.7435
-64.9325
 74.1606
-34.9376
 165.339
-744.538
 611.168
-174.154
-182.337
 496.668
-151.891
  -159.9
 497.949
-180.916
-174.056
 609.544
 -743.03
 165.089
p:
```

**And the stacktrace from gdb:**

```
bspline_fitting: /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/Block.h:122: Eigen::Block<XprType, BlockRows, BlockCols, InnerPanel>::Block(XprType&, Eigen::Index) [with XprType = Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1>; int BlockRows = 1; int BlockCols = 1; bool InnerPanel = false; Eigen::Index = long int]: Assertion `(i>=0) && ( ((BlockRows==1) && (BlockCols==XprType::ColsAtCompileTime) && i<xpr.rows()) ||((BlockRows==XprType::RowsAtCompileTime) && (BlockCols==1) && i<xpr.cols()))' failed.
Thread 1 "bspline_fitting" received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x00007ffff534e860 in raise () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
(gdb) where
#0  0x00007ffff534e860 in raise () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff534fec9 in abort () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007ffff53470bc in __assert_fail_base () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#3  0x00007ffff5347133 in __assert_fail () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#4  0x00005555559e7405 in Eigen::Block<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>, 1, 1, false>::Block (this=0x7fffffffd530, xpr=..., i=-4591537738753454899) at /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/Block.h:120
#5  0x00005555559ded86 in Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> >::row (this=0x7fffffffd4a0, i=-4591537738753454899) at /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/../plugins/BlockMethods.h:861
#6  0x00005555559e3f0f in Eigen::FullPivHouseholderQR<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1> >::_solve_impl<Eigen::CwiseUnaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_opposite_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> const>, Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> > (this=0x7fffffffdaa0, rhs=..., dst=...) at /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/QR/FullPivHouseholderQR.h:561
#7  0x00005555559dc75c in Eigen::internal::Assignment<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>, Eigen::Solve<Eigen::FullPivHouseholderQR<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1> >, Eigen::CwiseUnaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_opposite_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> const> >, Eigen::internal::assign_op<double, double>, Eigen::internal::Dense2Dense, void>::run (
    dst=..., src=...) at /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/Solve.h:147
#8  0x00005555559d4f4c in Eigen::internal::call_assignment_no_alias<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>, Eigen::Solve<Eigen::FullPivHouseholderQR<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1> >, Eigen::CwiseUnaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_opposite_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> const> >, Eigen::internal::assign_op<double, double> > (dst=..., src=..., func=...)
    at /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/AssignEvaluator.h:836
#9  0x00005555559cd8de in Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> >::_set_noalias<Eigen::Solve<Eigen::FullPivHouseholderQR<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1> >, Eigen::CwiseUnaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_opposite_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> const> > > (this=0x7fffffffd730, other=...)
    at /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/PlainObjectBase.h:728
#10 0x00005555559cd76f in Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> >::_init1<Eigen::Solve<Eigen::FullPivHouseholderQR<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1> >, Eigen::CwiseUnaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_opposite_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> const> >, Eigen::Solve<Eigen::FullPivHouseholderQR<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1> >, Eigen::CwiseUnaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_opposite_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> const> > > (this=0x7fffffffd730, other=...) at /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/PlainObjectBase.h:812
#11 0x00005555559c4d73 in Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>::Matrix<Eigen::Solve<Eigen::FullPivHouseholderQR<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1> >, Eigen::CwiseUnaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_opposite_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> const> > > (this=0x7fffffffd730, x=...) at /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/Matrix.h:296
#12 0x00005555559ba6fe in Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Solve<Eigen::FullPivHouseholderQR<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1> >, Eigen::CwiseUnaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_opposite_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> const> > >::eval (this=0x7fffffffd990) at /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/DenseBase.h:406
#13 0x00005555559aceaf in Eigen::operator<< <Eigen::Solve<Eigen::FullPivHouseholderQR<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1> >, Eigen::CwiseUnaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_opposite_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> const> > > (s=..., m=...) at /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/IO.h:220
#14 0x00005555559a2046 in vlw::o::exact_newton::converge<optimization::cinpact_scenario<std::function<void (std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)>, glm::vec<2, double, (glm::qualifier)0>, double>::cinpact_k_c_w_with_lls_and_exact_newton_and_wolfe()::{lambda()#1}, optimization::cinpact_scenario<std::function<void (std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)>, glm::vec<2, double, (glm::qualifier)0>, double>::cinpact_k_c_w_with_lls_and_exact_newton_and_wolfe()::{lambda(Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> const&)#2}, glm::vec<2, double, (glm::qualifier)0>, double>(optimization::cinpact_scenario<std::function<void (std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)>, glm::vec<2, double, (glm::qualifier)0>, double>::cinpact_k_c_w_with_lls_and_exact_newton_and_wolfe()::{lambda()#1}, optimization::cinpact_scenario<std::function<void (std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)>, glm::vec<2, double, (glm::qualifier)0>, double>::cinpact_k_c_w_with_lls_and_exact_newton_and_wolfe()::{lambda(Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> const&)#2}, vlw::o::non_linear_least_squares_problem<glm::vec<2, double, (glm::qualifier)0>, double>&, unsigned long, vlw::o::non_linear_least_squares_problem) (step_finished=..., alpha_search=..., problem=..., max_iterations=200, threshold=1.0000000000000001e-05)
    at /media/Crypt/School-Repos/curve-optimization/vlw/vlw/optimization/exact_newton.hpp:130
#15 0x000055555599945e in optimization::cinpact_scenario<std::function<void (std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)>, glm::vec<2, double, (glm::qualifier)0>, double>::cinpact_k_c_w_with_lls_and_exact_newton_and_wolfe() (this=0x555556143090) at /media/Crypt/School-Repos/curve-optimization/src/cinpact_scenario.hpp:825
#16 0x0000555555994586 in optimization::cinpact_scenario<std::function<void (std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)>, glm::vec<2, double, (glm::qualifier)0>, double>::perform7() (this=0x555556143090) at /media/Crypt/School-Repos/curve-optimization/src/cinpact_scenario.hpp:818
#17 0x0000555555923332 in CurveWindow::perform7 (this=0x7fffffffe090) at /media/Crypt/School-Repos/curve-optimization/src/main.cpp:887
#18 0x0000555555921ac1 in CurveWindow::keyPressEvent (this=0x7fffffffe090, ev=0x7fffffffde30) at /media/Crypt/School-Repos/curve-optimization/src/main.cpp:683
#19 0x00007ffff67d5a35 in QWindow::event(QEvent*) () from /usr/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5
#20 0x0000555555a67d01 in OpenGLWindow::event (this=0x7fffffffe090, event=0x7fffffffde30) at /media/Crypt/School-Repos/curve-optimization/src/openglwindow.cpp:106
#21 0x00007ffff625806b in QCoreApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /usr/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#22 0x00007ffff62581e0 in QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /usr/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#23 0x00007ffff67c6012 in QGuiApplicationPrivate::processKeyEvent(QWindowSystemInterfacePrivate::KeyEvent*) () from /usr/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5
#24 0x00007ffff67cb166 in QGuiApplicationPrivate::processWindowSystemEvent(QWindowSystemInterfacePrivate::WindowSystemEvent*) () from /usr/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5
#25 0x00007ffff67a2bbc in QWindowSystemInterface::sendWindowSystemEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /usr/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5
#26 0x00007fffeef5015d in ?? () from /usr/lib/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5
#27 0x00007ffff625682b in QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /usr/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#28 0x00007ffff625fb18 in QCoreApplication::exec() () from /usr/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#29 0x000055555592354d in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe238) at /media/Crypt/School-Repos/curve-optimization/src/main.cpp:914
(gdb) up
#1  0x00007ffff534fec9 in abort () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
(gdb)
#2  0x00007ffff53470bc in __assert_fail_base () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
(gdb)
#3  0x00007ffff5347133 in __assert_fail () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
(gdb)
#4  0x00005555559e7405 in Eigen::Block<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>, 1, 1, false>::Block (this=0x7fffffffd530, xpr=..., i=-4591537738753454899) at /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/Block.h:120
120           eigen_assert( (i>=0) && (
(gdb)
#5  0x00005555559ded86 in Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> >::row (this=0x7fffffffd4a0, i=-4591537738753454899) at /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/../plugins/BlockMethods.h:861
861       return RowXpr(derived(), i);
(gdb)
#6  0x00005555559e3f0f in Eigen::FullPivHouseholderQR<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1> >::_solve_impl<Eigen::CwiseUnaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_opposite_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> const>, Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> > (this=0x7fffffffdaa0, rhs=..., dst=...) at /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/QR/FullPivHouseholderQR.h:561
561         c.row(k).swap(c.row(m_rows_transpositions.coeff(k)));
(gdb) print k
$1 = 0
(gdb) print m_rows_transpositions.coeff(k)
$2 = (const Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Matrix<long, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1> >::Scalar &) @0x555556143a80: -4591537738753454899
```

Comment: Could you provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? As simple as possible with a `main()`

Comment: I answered to the same question 2 days ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47800872, be careful with [auto](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicPitfalls.html).

Comment: Thanks @ggael - that was it. I can't mark your comment as an answer, but if you actually answer I will happily mark it as the answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the correct way to solve a least square equation with eigen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47800872/what-is-the-correct-way-to-solve-a-least-square-equation-with-eigen)

Answer (score 1):

This was a double failure on my part.

1. I didn't read the documentation - https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicPitfalls.html
2. I didn't successfully find an already answered question with the answer in it: [What is the correct way to solve a least square equation with eigen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47800872/what-is-the-correct-way-to-solve-a-least-square-equation-with-eigen)

Basically, if you use auto instead of the appropriate Matrix types, then you actually get a type that is an abstract expression. This causes problems, sometimes performances sometimes dangling references.  Don't use auto unless you know what type the compiler is deducing and really want to use that type.